# How to perform a haptic feedback in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, haptic-feedback

Using jetpack compose, for a clickevent how to perform haptic feedback. I am new to jetpack compose.
This is what i tried -

```
val hapticFeedback = LocalHapticFeedback

@Composable
fun Tab() {
    Row() {
        Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = text)
        if (selected) {
            // i tried both the following ways, none are working. 
            hapticFeedback.current.performHapticFeedback(
                HapticFeedbackType(10)
            )
            hapticFeedback.current.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.TextHandleMove)
....
            Spacer(Modifier.width(12.dp))
            Text(text.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()))
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to see the text when it is getting selected, but not getting a subtle vibrating feedback.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In version `rc-01` of Compose you can use only two types of Haptic Feedback: `HapticFeedbackType.LongPress` or `HapticFeedbackType.TextHandleMove`.

```
val haptic = LocalHapticFeedback.current
Row(
    Modifier.clickable {
        haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
    }
)
```

Comment: `HapticFeedbackType.TextHandleMove` , doesn't seems to be working when performed a clickable action only `HapticFeedbackType.LongPress`  works.

Comment: It doesn't work at all

Comment: Apparently,  Modifier.pointerInput() will not work if you use Modifier.clickable. I have some logic that needs to be performed in pointerInput. Any workaround for this?

Comment: what is ``context `` for?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine with me in the onDragStart method of the detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress modifier function.

Answer (score 28):

Currently (Compose UI `1.1.0-beta03`) only `LongPress` and `TextHandleMove` are supported via

```
val haptic = LocalHapticFeedback.current
Button(onClick = {
    haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
}) { ... }
```

as @nglauber answer said.

I guess it is because of the multi-platform support for Compose Desktop.

There's another way, however, if you are on Android and you do not need Compose Desktop compatibility, it's fairly easy to use it:

```
val view = LocalView.current
Button(onClick = {
    view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP)
}) { ... }
```

The `HapticFeedbackConstants` class has [a lot of constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants).

Comment: For me, the haptic version didn't work but the view one did.

Answer (score 9):

On my phone (and other devices I've tested on) neither `LongPress` nor `TextHandleMove` makes the phone vibrate.

We worked around this before we moved to Compose like this:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.view.HapticFeedbackConstants
import android.view.View
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager

fun View.vibrate() = reallyPerformHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY)
fun View.vibrateStrong() = reallyPerformHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)

private fun View.reallyPerformHapticFeedback(feedbackConstant: Int) {
    if (context.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
        // Don't mess with a blind person's vibrations
        return
    }
    // Either this needs to be set to true, or android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" needs to be set in XML
    isHapticFeedbackEnabled = true

    // Most of the constants are off by default: for example, clicking on a button doesn't cause the phone to vibrate anymore
    // if we still want to access this vibration, we'll have to ignore the global settings on that.
    performHapticFeedback(feedbackConstant, HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING)
}

private fun Context.isTouchExplorationEnabled(): Boolean {
    // can be null during unit tests
    val accessibilityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager?
    return accessibilityManager?.isTouchExplorationEnabled ?: false
}
```

For now we still have to use this code and access it from Compose like in [Daniele Segato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285552/1199110):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun VibratingButton() {
    val view = LocalView.current
    Button(onClick = {
        view.vibrate()
    }) { ... }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: I found view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
 worked with the shorter snippet; Modifier from the other answer appeared not to do anything for me.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this worked well when the user presses down the button. Using Compose `1.2.0-beta01`

```kotlin
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

val hapticFeedback = LocalHapticFeedback.current
LaunchedEffect(key1 = isPressed) {
    if (isPressed) {
        hapticFeedback.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Be aware tho this will only work if haptic is enabled in your android settings.

Answer (score -4):

Add the feedback logic inside the `Modifier.clickable {...}` applied to the `Row`